# Git host for submodules and continuous integration

Tags: git, ssh, continuous-integration

We have one server (debian) on which the git repositories are located. Also the same server is used for continuous integration.
During the build step a git repository is cloned/updated with its submodules. The host of a submodule is subdomain.domain.tld. Note that this host is exactly this one server. The user running the the CI is bamboo. The host of the submodule is specified without a user such that when contacting the host through ssh it is automatically prefixed with the current user. This works perfectly for us developers because every developer has a user on this server.

The problem is with the build server. When the git submodules are updated the build server tries to connect to bamboo@subdomain.domain.tld instead of bamboo@localhost. It can't connect because there is no ssh key available for bamboo@subdomain.domain.tld.

For now I just uploaded a key using

```
ssh-copy-id -i /home/bamboo/.ssh/id_rsa.pub subdomain.domain.tld
```

But I believe it is weird/incorrect to upload a key for the same user only for a different URL.

Is this solution correct/safe or is there a far easier solution to this problem?

Comment: Not an SSH expert but if it works and it is documented I don't see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as designed, and this is not weird.

You could do this in the `~/.ssh/config` on the build server:

```
Host sub0.domain.tld sub1.domain.tld sub2.domain.tld sub3.domain.tld
HostName localhost
# User git
# Compression no
# ControlMaster auto
```

Comment: It tells your local ssh client to use `localhost` to connect to the named hosts